# Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here :

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

My code is :

```java
public class EventDataSQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my.db";
}

public class Test extends Activity {
    EventDataSQLHelper eventsData;

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("onDestroy");
  
        close();
        if (db!=null){
       
        db.close();
        
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void close() {
    eventsData.close();
}
```

I have closed the db here.. In all my activities except this its working(no exception is shown).. Here when i press back button from this Test activity the below exception is thrown

```
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.tesy.connect/databases/test.db' 
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1810)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:540)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:158)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at com.connect.Test.getEvents(Connect_EY.java:755)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at com.connect.Test.onCreate(Connect_EY.java:662)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
```

The exception is thrown on this getEvents line :

```java
public class Test extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pageview);

    startRefreshActivity();
    try { /* If No Record Exists Create a New One */
    eventsData = new EventDataSQLHelper(this);
    Cursor cursor = getEvents();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    } 
}

private Cursor getEvents() {
    try {
        db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(EventDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, null,
            null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        return cursor;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occured : " + ex.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Exception :

```
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at com.testconnect.Test.getEvents(Test.java:755)
02-14 15:59:34.642: ERROR/Database(535):     at com.testconnect.Test.onCreate(Test.java:662)
```

Comment: try closing the cursor at onStop(); try this if(db!=null){     db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
}

Comment: @Vamsi I have tried that but null pointer exception is thrown there

Comment: Have you implemented onCreate() and onUpgrade() for the SQLiteOpenHelper class?

Comment: @Vamsi I have implemented  @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  and    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { in my  calss public class EventDataSQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the exception. I was calling

```
 db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
```

twice thats why the exception is thrown

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
     Cursor cursor = getEvents();
     startManagingCursor(cursor);
     cursor.close();
```

?

Comment: I have done this.. but still showing the exception. its shown in the line  Cursor cursor = getEvents(); inside the getEvents method     db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.query(EventDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, null,
      null, null, null, null);    In the Logcat  the exception is thrown in these line

Comment: Im also facing this Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here :  Problem.. How to reslove that ..Pls Help

Answer (score 1):

Did you try After pass return value close cursor  like `cursor.close`

```
  private Cursor getEvents() {
     try {
            db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(EventDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, null,
             null, null, null, null);
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return cursor;

         } catch (Exception ex) {
              System.out.println("Exception Occured : " + ex.toString());
              return null;
      }
```