# Application did not close the cursor or database object android

Tags: android

I am trying to lookup for contact name by number from contacts book in an AsyncTask. Sometimes I get the following error which, I think, causes application crash. Any help please.

Logcat

```
08-05 09:00:49.627 24988-27371/com.fake.fake E/CursorLeakDetecter: PossibleCursorLeak:content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/%2B923310433708,QueryCounter:5
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:323)
    at com.fake.fake.GV.getContactName(GV.java:177)
    at com.fake.fake.MySQLiteHelper.GetNumbers(MySQLiteHelper.java:361)
    at com.fake.fake.MainActivity$taskLoadContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:930)
    at com.fake.fake.MainActivity$taskLoadContacts.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:921)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Retrieving contact numbers from database.

```
 public ArrayList<MyMessageDetails> GetNumbers(String query) {
        ArrayList<MyMessageDetails> numbers = new ArrayList<MyMessageDetails>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MyMessageDetails item = new MyMessageDetails();
                item.setNumber(cursor.getString(0));
                String name = GV.getContactName(item.getNumber());    
                if (name == null) {
                    name = item.getNumber();
                }
                item.setName(name);
                item.setTime(cursor.getString(3));
                numbers.add(item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return numbers;
    }
```

Retrieving contact name.

```
 public static String getContactName(String phoneNumber) {
        if (phoneNumber != null) {
            ContentResolver cr = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                return "";
            }
            String contactName = null;
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }

            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return contactName;
        }

        return phoneNumber;
    }
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991179/application-did-not-close-the-cursor-or-database-object-that-was-opened-here?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link, but error is coming from "getContactName" not from GetNumbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So couple of issues i see here.

First of all, always surround your queries in a `try catch finally` block and close all cursor and db operations in `finally` block. So that for both your methods.

And I think what you are doing wrong here is first calling `GetNumbers()` method and after that `getContactName()`. Now you don't close db in `GetNumbers()` in the code and hence after that whatever operations you try to do on the db will give this error and hence error comes in `getContactName()`

Comment: Thanks for "try catch finally" suggestion. I want my db to remain open, that is why it is not closed.  Should I close cursor also in finally block as well?

Comment: Yes you should do that in finally block. And its best to close the db and open again when and if needed. or you can perform all db operations in that method that are related to that part of the data and close it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Cursor#close()` after you finish reading the data from it. Example:

```
Cursor cursor = ...
try {
    // fetch whatever you need here
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks let me check.